# Add Toast in button.setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

**How to Toast is add when changing picture ?**

```
  button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            if (bIcon) 
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add1);
             else 
                         button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add2);
                bIcon = !bIcon;                                             
        }   });
```

**When I do like this**

```
 button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            if (bIcon) 
                button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add1);
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "drawable.add1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             else 
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add2);
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "drawable.add2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bIcon = !bIcon;                                             
        }
    });
```

**Changing the image is not**

Comment: what is your issue? For sure you missed brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-** The problem here is in your `if` and `else` loop.

**-** When we have a `if or else condition` containing **single statement** its **not necessary to have braces at the starting and ending points**, but when there are **multiple statements to be contained within the condition then u must use braces.**

**Eg:**

```
boolean bIcon = false;
button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        if (bIcon == false) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add1);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "drawable.add1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        bIcon = true;
        }
        else {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.add2);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "drawable.add2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bIcon = false;                
        }                             
    }
});
```

Comment: Now try the edited code........... I haven't done any major changes but just made the understand-ability of the code easier.........